# Prompting user to accept self-signed SSL using DefaultHttpClient in Android

Tags: android, http, ssl

I'm developing an Android 4.0 app that connects to Microsoft Exchange.

At present, I'm having difficulty dealing with self-signed certificates, as they just get rejected. I've tried a lot of the solutions on SO, building new SocketFactories and TrustManagers, but none of them offer a real solution.

Ideally, I'd like to prompt the user to inform them the SSL cert cannot be verified and if they accept that, I'd like to download the certificate being presented, store it and use it for the next connection. Or something similar to this process (like Firefox's SSL exceptions list)

Unfortunately, the only examples I have found rely on the certificate being installed into a TrustStore on the device using command line tools. This doesn't help when a customer downloads it. I just want a simple accept/reject dialog.

I could blindly trust all SSL certificates, but I'd rather do something slightly more secure.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? Is what I'd like to do even possible? If the accept/reject can't be done, then a blind acceptance of self-signed certs is the best I can manage.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From android ICS there is the [KeyChain class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html) where you can store additional trusted certificates.

Your software could do something like that:

1. Create a dedicated [X509TrustManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html) in order to handle unknown server certificate (see [X509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html#checkServerTrusted%28java.security.cert.X509Certificate%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) method)
2. When the server certificate is unknown create an Intent to prompt the user to install the certificate with [KeyChain.createInstallIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html#createInstallIntent%28%29)

The certificate should be available for the future connections.

Comment: Thanks. Your method lines up with a blog post I just found - http://nelenkov.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html. I'm trying it now.

Comment: I added the certificates from the untrusted chain directly to the KeyStore using setKeyEntry(). This is now working a treat! Thx.